# Image generation failure through modified byte array using both java and opencv?

Tags: java, opencv

In my program I am reading an image using java, taking its byte array and applying modifications to it by applying random functions. Now during the entire process the size of array is maintained but when I am trying to construct an image using the byte array an empty image is obtained. I have tried using both java and opencv to reconstruct the image (the image is grayscale image of 440*442 size .png type).

opencv code:

```
byte[] bytesArrayForImage=new byte[array.length];
for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    bytesArrayForImage[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(array[i]);

}
Mat mat = new Mat(440,442, CvType.CV_8UC1);

mat.put(0,0, bytesArrayForImage);

 String filename111 = Path;
 Highgui.imwrite(filename111, mat);
```

java code:

```
BufferedImage image=ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytearray));
ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(C:\\Users\\domin\\Desktop\\Sop\\,"modified.png"));
```